# Legally invoking a pure virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, pure-virtual

I'm sure we've all seen code that crashes due to a bug that results in a pure virtual function being called. One simple example is like this:

```
struct Base
{
    Base() { method(); }

    virtual void method() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    void method() {};
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

In this case, the call to `method()` in the `Base` constructor is specifically cited as undefined behaviour by section 10.4/6 of the C++ standard, so it's no surprise that we end up crashing. (Both g++ and Clang warn about this, and in fact linking fails with g++ with this example, though Clang succeeds.)

But, just for fun, **can anybody come up with a way to invoke a pure virtual function which does not rely on undefined behaviour?**

(I suppose you could argue that if such a method exists then there's a defect in the C++ standard, but I'm just curious...)

**EDIT:** Several answers guys and thank you, but I should have made it clear that I realise it's legal to make a non-virtual call to a pure virtual function (providing a definition exists somewhere). I was more wondering whether there is any clever loophole in the laws which could result in a virtual call, and thus most likely a crash in the common case of having no definition.

For example, perhaps via multiple inheritance one could perform some clever (legal) cast, but end up with the "wrong" (unimplemented) PV `method()` being called, that sort of thing. I just thought it was a fun brainteaser :-)

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for the [tag:language-lawyer] tag, but you're at 5 already. You might consider re-tagging.

Comment: @Angew good call, changed

Comment: Well, there is nothing that prevents you from implementing that pure virtual function, and then its called from that ctor context just fine.

Comment: Three words: pure virtual destructor. Google it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, but would it be a *pure* virtual function anymore if it is implemented in the base class?

Comment: @user2079303 Yes. As long as it's `= 0`, it's a *pure virtual function* and causes the class containing it to be abstract.

Comment: Angew: Ok, good to know. @Tristan, Are you asking specifically "How to invoke a pure virtual function inside a constructor?" (Which you cite as UB) or just "How to invoke pure virtual function from the `Base` class?" which you can do outside constructor just fine as I understand.

Comment: @Angew: The example above was just the first way that came to mind to call a PV method, I'm not specifically asking about constructors. In fact, I should have made clear that I meant *unimplemented* PV functions; basically the question comes down to "can you trick the runtime into calling an unimplemented PV function (and thus crashing) without breaking any rules?"

Comment: @PlasmaHH: It's not "called from that ctor context just fine"; it's still undefined behaviour to call it virtually.

Comment: @TristanBrindle I don't really understand your amended question. You already found where the standard says that a virtual call to a pure virtual function during construction and destruction is UB. A class with pure virtual functions is abstract and cannot be constructed, so other than during construction and destruction of a derived class, it seems obvious that a virtual call can never resolve to a pure virtual function, and that'll be why the answers focus on non-virtual calls. If you take non-virtual calls out of the picture, there's nothing left, is there?

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly legal to call a pure virtual function non-virtually:

```
Derived d;
d.Base::method();
```

Of course, this requires the function to be defined, which isn't the case in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean with possible. Here's one which compiles successfully, but will most likely result in a linker error:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    void method() { Base::method(); };
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  d.method();
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/vxtDPT)

It compiles because nothing prevents a pure virtual function from actually having a body as well. That can be provided in the same translation unit (in a separate definition), or in a different translation unit. That's why it's a linker error and not a compiler one - just that the function has no body here doesn't mean it doesn't have one elsewhere.

Comment: The only thing you can't do is provide the body alongside the in-class declaration. (i.e. after the `= 0` part) Syntax stuff.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I know, I was after "call one without a body." Answer amended

Answer (score 2):

A pure virutal function can have an implementation. Best example: a pure virtual destructor must have an implementation because all destructors will be called when an an object is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Taking out the linker error from @Angew's answer. Not sure about the undefined behavior happening here...

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

void Base::method(){}

struct Derived : Base
{
    void method() { Base::method(); };
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  d.method();
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6d9c1e83a210f90)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment to Angews answer (like PlasmaHH did?)